# Is it possible to use the mouse scroll wheel to adjust parameters in Serum in FL Studio?

Tags: fl-studio

Is it possible to use the mouse scroll wheel to adjust parameters in Serum in FL Studio? I unsuccessfully tried with FL Studio 12 and FL Studio 20, even though using the mouse scroll wheel does adjust parameters for other (non-Serum) windows in FL Studio.